# Separate data based on categories across columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split, conditional-statements

My data set looks like this:

```
Col1 Col2
AA    ID1
BB    ID2
CC    ID3
BB    ID4
AA    ID5
```

I would like to separate values in Col2 based on the categories of Col1. The final product would look like this:

```
AA   BB  CC
ID1  ID2 ID3
ID5  ID4 NA
```

I have been trying different for loops without success. I am thinking there must be a much easier way.
Any chance someone would know a simple trick?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `dcast` or `spread`

Comment: Thank you, spread works. I did not know that function! For instance: data %>% spread(Col1, Col2)

Comment: Apologize for duplicating that question. I did not find it until @akrun pointed it. Feel free to close the question if needed

Comment: Its okay.  I tagged it as dupe.  It is easier to find answers on google when there are more dupe links